# How to set property of class in Javascript ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have class in ES6 like this:

```
class temp
{
    name = "";
    type = 0;
    required = true;
    range = false;
    default = "";
    ...
    ...
}
```

the temp class has many property, i can't give all of them in constructor.

How to create list of temp class like :

```
let list = [
    new Input(name="test1", type=0, ...),
    new Input(required=true, default="d", ...),
    new Input(type=1, default="s", ...),
    new Input(name="test2", default="s", ...)
]
```

Comment: Time to study some tutorials on using javascript classes

Answer (score 3):

Replace your class with this one:

```
class Input {
  construtor(name, type, required, range) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.required = required;
    this.range = range;
  }
}
```

Whatever you want to initialize in your class, use `constructor`.
If you put them outside of the constructor OR function it will throw an error.

Don't use `default` as a variable because it is a reserved key in JavaScript.

Also if you see your class name (`temp`) it is different from the name mentioned in the list (`Input`). Replace it.

Comment: the temp class has many property, i can't give all of them in constructor

Answer (score 1):

To set the properties, add a constructor method that takes the property values as arguments to your class and then within that constructor method, you can set the class properties

```
constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

Comment: the temp class has many property, i can't give all of them in constructor

Answer (score 0):

Firstly in your class, you need a constructor if you want to be able to instantiate it with certain properties

```
class temp{
    constructor(name = "", type, required = "true", range="false", tdefault = ""){
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.required = required;
        this.range = range;
        this.tdefault = tdefault;
    }
}
```

Then you can construct them anonymously in the array

```
let list = [
     new temp("test1", 0, true, false, "d"),
     etc,
     etc
  ]
```

btw the = "true" and other stuff in the constructor is the ES6 way of giving things a default value.